# Why doesn't Google Fit distance match fit app?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

The [google fit faq](https://developers.google.com/fit/faq) states that in order to match the distance and step values of the official google fit app, we should be using the following data request

```
DataSource ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS = new DataSource.Builder()
       .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
       .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
       .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
       .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
       .build();
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
       .aggregate(ESTIMATED_STEP_DELTAS,    DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
       .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
       .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
       .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
       .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
       .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
       .build();
```

The above returns the correct step count (matches the google fit app) but the distance returned is always different than what is displayed on the official google fit application.

I have tried constructing a similar `DataSource` for distance by using `merge_distance_delta` streamName, this returns the same distance that is displayed on google https://fit.google.com/u/0/

```
 DataSource ESTIMATED_DISTANCE_DELTAS =   DataSource.Builder()
                        .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
                        .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
                        .setStreamName("merge_distance_delta")
                        .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
                        .build()
```

Using the above data source always matches what is displayed on https://fit.google.com/u/0/ and sometimes matches the official google fit app.

**The sync to google fit cloud seems to be random and there is no way to force it so if the google fit app is recording this distance, is there a way to figure out how its calculating the distance and why is it different than what is returned by

    DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA**?

**Is there a specific streamName that I can use to get the same distance that the google fit app uses?**

Comment: have you found any solution for this ?

Comment: No, unfortunately I have not had the time to dig too deep into it.  Based on my research it seems like the syncs to servers are random and there is no good way to control it.  I'll post an answer when I get time to revisit this.

Comment: hey @Naveed Did you get any solution ?? 
I have same issue , I am facing data mismatch issue . Help will be highly appreciated

Comment: I haven't been able to get a solution yet. I tried reaching out to Google on their Google+ forums but no one responded. I've done some research and noticed that there are other fitness apps that don't have the same data Google fit app.